# Check if my range is overwriting another range

Tags: javascript, math, range

Let's say i have a range of numbers, for example : `5 to 8`

Then i have an array of existing ranges :

```
let arrayOfExistingRanges = [
  { 
   id: 1, 
   start: 1, 
   end: 2 
  },
  { 
   id: 2, 
   start: 1, 
   end: 5 
  },
  { 
   id: 3, 
   start: 5, 
   end: 6 
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to make sure that i don't overwrite/overlap any existing range with my new range.

Basically getting each objects of my `arrayOfExistingRanges` where my range is overlapping them in any way.

Below i made a list of possibilities to check against, but i would like to know if there would be a better way than to check individually each possibility..

[image]

Comment: So what do you want to do ultimately?, merge the overlapping ranges?

Comment: Get the objects that would be overwritten by my new range

Comment: please add a consistent example.

Comment: @Owow - you mean overlapped ?

Comment: Yes, basically check if 5 to 8 is overlapping one of my range in my `arrayOfExistingRanges`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that a range would not get affected by the new range if:

1. Either the range finishes *before* the new range starts.
   **OR**
2. The range starts *after* the new range ends.

Based on those conditions, you can have a function that says whether a given range is *safe* or not;

```
const isSafe =(newRange, existingRange) => 
   (existingRange.end <= newRange.start || newRange.end <= existingRange.start );
```

By, *safe* I mean whether the `newRange` and `existingRange` would overlap or not. If `isSafe` returns `true`, they would not overlap.

Here is how you can use `filter()` to filter out the overlapping ranges:

```
const newRange = { id: 10, start: 2, end: 3 };
const affected = arrayOfExistingRanges.filter((x) => !isSafe(newRange, x));
```

Here is the complete code:

```js
const isSafe =(newRange, existingRange) => 
   (existingRange.end <= newRange.start || newRange.end <= existingRange.start );

const arrayOfExistingRanges = [
  { 
   id: 1, 
   start: 1, 
   end: 2 
  },
  { 
   id: 2, 
   start: 1, 
   end: 5 
  },
  { 
   id: 3, 
   start: 5, 
   end: 6 
  }]

const newRange = { id: 10, start: 2, end: 3 };
const affected = arrayOfExistingRanges.filter((x) => !isSafe(newRange, x));

console.log(affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter by checking the range. The result contains only ranges who are overlapping the given range.

```js
var ranges = [
        { id: 1, start: 5, end: 8 },
        { id: 2, start: 4, end: 6 },
        { id: 3, start: 7, end: 9 },
        { id: 4, start: 6, end: 7 },
        { id: 5, start: 4, end: 9},
        { id: 6, start: 1, end: 2, out: true },
        { id: 7, start: 11, end: 12, out: true },
        { id: 8, start: 1, end: 5, out: true },
        { id: 9, start: 8, end: 10, out: true },
        { id: 10, start: 5, end: 6 },
        { id: 11, start: 7, end: 8 },
        { id: 12, start: 5, end: 8 },
        { id: 13, start: 5, end: 10 },
        { id: 14, start: 4, end: 8 },
    ],
    start = 5,
    end = 8,
    overlapping = ranges.filter(o => o.end > start && o.start < end);

console.log(overlapping);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayOfExistingRanges = [
  { 
   id: 1, 
   start: 1, 
   end: 2 
  },
  { 
   id: 2, 
   start: 1, 
   end: 5 
  },
  { 
   id: 3, 
   start: 5, 
   end: 6 
  }
]

//new range
const n = { 
   start: 1, 
   end: 2 
}
const notOverlaping = arrayOfExistingRanges.filter((r) => {
  return ( n.start >= r.end && n.end  <= r.start)
});
 console.log(arrayOfExistingRanges.filter(n => !notOverlaping.includes(n)););
```

Comment: In your "notOverlapping" function, you are using the wrong operator. There should be && instead of ||.
Unfortunately, I don't have enough rating to downgrade to second.